# E[Log(x+a)] when x has gamma distribution

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

Is there a formula for this using built-in functions in matlab or mathematica like the Gamma functions or Ei's?

> $$\int_0^\infty \log(x+a)e^{-\alpha x}x^\beta dx. $$

Thanks.

Comment: You should at least tell us something about the parameters. I assue that they're real? What are the ranges of $a$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$? Are there any additional constraints or relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's [`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) apparently can't solve this (R2013b), but if you have Mathematica you can use [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html):

```
Simplify[Integrate[Log[x+a] Exp[-alpha x] x^beta, {x, 0, Infinity}]]
```

which returns a long result in terms of a $_2F_2$ [hypergeometric function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) using [`HypergeometricPFQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html), a [`PolyGamma`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolyGamma.html) function (specifically a [digamma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)), and several gamma functions and trigonometric functions. These can all be readily translated to Matlab if desired. Matlab's [`hypergeom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html) does require the symbolic math toolbox even if you want floating-point results. Also, the Matlab "equivalent" of Mathematica's `PolyGamma` is the [`psi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/psi.html) function.

Because of the presence of the hypergeometric function (and it's not one of the nicer ones), if this is a computational problem rather than one of analysis, you might be better off trying to solve the integral via quadrature (e.g., [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) in Matlab). This could prove to be more computationally efficient and sufficiently accurate if appropriate tolerances are specified and parameters don't place the equation in extreme/unstable conditions. However, it's also possible that you can find a suitable approximation for the hypergeometric function in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to see if Mathematica is using an inefficient way of representing this integral and there are more simplified versions of it - I have encountered something like this in the past. That being said though, seems like quadrature is the way to go for computation since I haven't been able to bring it down to formulas only involving simpler functions like Gamma.

Comment: @Ali It can't hurt to try and it will be a good comparison. Just be sure to validate the quadrature against the analytic solution.